# Im getting the errors: "y values ​must be 0 <= y <= 1", "object 'GLM.1' not found" and "The model/ Templates are no longer available"

Tags: r, statistics, glm, r-commander

So, I have a binomial variable (S and N) and the Generalized linear model on Rcommander isnt working. Attached is a picture of the rcommander window. It is in portuguese, but the logic is the same: the 1st variable added under "splines" (on the left) is the **qualitative binomial variable and the next one is another qualitative variable (and so are all of the other ones on my database)** Then I click ok.

The thing is, I am getting the following errors/warnings :

```
RcmdrMsg: [5] ERROR: y values ​​must be 0 <= y <= 1

RcmdrMsg: [6] ERROR: Error evaluating argument 'object' in method selection for function 'summary'

Warning in sprintf(gettextRcmdr("the model %s is no longer available"), : one argument not used by format 'The model is no longer available'

RcmdrMsg: [7] ERROR: Templates are no longer available

RcmdrMsg: [8] ERROR: object 'GLM.1' not found
```

I´ve tried writing the script like

`GLM.1 <- glm(A.demanda.foi.atendida.e.foi.no.prazo. ~ UF, family=binomial(logit), data=Tabela_Procon_última)`, but it isnt working either.

I would REALLY appreciate it if someone could give me an insight as to what is going on.

Thank you very much!

This is a assignment about quality control. Right now I need to see which variables really influence the response variable.

I have tried doing that by using the Generalized linear model tool on Rcommander but it didn't work. I tried typing the script:

```
GLM.1 <- glm(A.demanda.foi.atendida.e.foi.no.prazo. ~ UF, family=binomial(logit), data=Tabela_Procon_última)
```

But it also didnt work.

All of my variables are qualitative.The errors I am getting are the following:

I am getting the following errors/warnings :

```
RcmdrMsg: [5] ERROR: y values ​​must be 0 <= y <= 1

RcmdrMsg: [6] ERROR: Error evaluating argument 'object' in method selection for function 'summary'

Warning in sprintf(gettextRcmdr("the model %s is no longer available"), : one argument not used by format 'The model is no longer available'

RcmdrMsg: [7] ERROR: Templates are no longer available RcmdrMsg+

RcmdrMsg: [8] ERROR: object 'GLM.1' not found
```

thank you

Comment: What do you get when you run `summary(Tabela_Procon_última$A.demanda.foi.atendida.e.foi.no.prazo.)`?

Comment: Hi, Phill! I see this: Length     Class      Mode 
     8016 character character

Comment: Your variable needs to be in numeric format instead of character.

Comment: Hi, Phill! So, change from character to factor?

Comment: NO. While `factor(.)` stores internally as an integer, it is treated wholly as categorical (possibly ordered) data, in which case many math-like operations will still fail (worse, if they succeed, it is not always intuitive if they are working on the number as we see or the integer-index stored internally). The recommendation as for `numeric`, which means `as.numeric` in my book.